# Intuitive idea of adapted processes with respect to "information"

Tags: probability, probability-theory, soft-question, stochastic-processes, intuition

My text says the following,

"If the process $X_{n}$ is adapted to the filtration $\mathcal{F}_{n}$ the value $X_{n}(\omega)$ is known to us at time $n$."

This sounds wierd to me since it is all still random stuff, nothing is said about a realisation of $X_{n}$ up until $n$ for instance.

At time $n$ we ONLY KNOW that a certain amout of sets are in $\mathcal{F}_{n}$ . What he must mean is that given that we know which sets  in $\mathcal{F}_{n}$ that $\omega$  "belongs" and "not belongs" to for all $\omega$, then we know $X_{n}(\omega)$, is this correct?

I also get confused by his statement regarding filtration in general i.e

"For any $\omega$ the information we have about it given the filtaration at time $n$ is exactly the values of any $\mathcal{F_{n}}$ measureable function"

This again must be dependant of the information which sets in $\mathcal{F}_{n}$ that $\omega$ belongs to and does not belong to, for all $\omega$. I think my second problem is the same as the one above in term of thinking about these matters. I know this is kind of a stupid question since it all seams reasonable but it would be nice if anyone would care to confirm this.

Update

Part of the misconseption was that I regarding the realisation wrong. As far I understand now the sigma algebra evolves with the index of the process and so does the $\omega$ in some sense aswell, the "whole" $\omega$ is not a factor until one considers the whole process i.e all $n$ are realized. Until then sets in each $\mathcal{F}_{n}$ are such that one can distingusih between paths up to time $n$. The remaining times are still unknown and are still within the same event.

Comment: I guess it is Williams' book!

Comment: @Arash it is pretty dense :) But worth the effort. Somtimes he leave to much to the imagination tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"If the process $X_{n}$ is adapted to the filtration $\mathcal{F}_{n}$ the value $X_{n}(\omega)$ is known to us at time $n$."

This means that the value of process will be known to you *not before* the time $n$. If you know $X_1,\dots,X_{n-1}$, i.e., $\mathcal F_{n-1}$, you cannot *predict* $X_n$. Look at it from conditional expectation point of view:
$$
E(X_n\mid \mathcal F_{n-1})\neq X_{n}.
$$
This is the intuition behind the adapted process. Basically only $\mathcal F_n$ (or future sigma-algebras) contains what we can know about $X_n$.

---

"For any $\omega$ the information we have about it given the filtaration at time $n$ is exactly the values of any $\mathcal{F_{n}}$ measureable function"

This is another way of saying that any information you can have about $\omega$ at time $n$ is simply included in $\mathcal{F}_n$. Knowing $\mathcal F_n$ and $f$ a $\mathcal F_n$-measurable function, $f(\omega)$ is a random variable which gives information about $\omega$ knowing $\mathcal F_n$.

Let's have an example. Suppose that we are interested in knowing  if $\omega$ belongs to $A\subset \Omega$. If $A\in\mathcal F_n$, this information can be represented as $1(\omega\in A)$ which is a $\mathcal F_n$-measurable function.

Comment: This does not quite answer what I was looking for, maybe due to my poor formulation. Knowing X(ω) to me means that that I know that it is equal to say 5. The sigma algebra at some time is just a collection of sets. A collection of sets doest tell me anything unless I ask then somthing. Asking them could be to "does ω belong to you?" and all sets could say yes or no. But knowing a sigma algebra is just knowning the sets. A sigma algebra can therefore not contain any information but only possible information about X but maybe that is what you and Williams wanna say? or maybe I am missing smt..

Comment: Maybe you can replace "know" with "observe" and read it again. And you are right; the sigma-algebra is itself set of possible events. At time $n$ these events belong to $\mathcal F_n$ and those before. So any information about $\omega$ can be inferred from the sets of $\mathcal F_n$, hence the values of measurable functions.

Comment: right, I think there is just same small leap here because of wording. When you say "So any information about ω can be inferred from the sets of $\mathcal{F_{n}}$", you mean by checking weather the realised ω is in them, and from doing that to all sets,get the actual value say X(ω)=a

Comment: Not really, at time $n$ and by observing the process you may not know the realization of $\omega$; exactly because $\{\omega\}$ might not belong to $\mathcal F_n$. All you can know about $\omega$ at time $n$ is determined but what you have in $\mathcal F_n$.

Comment: Oh, so knowing $\mathcal{F_{n}}$ is like some kind of "partial reliasition"? and we can see if some ω's are still possiblites? There is in some sense a certain subsets of Ω for which the process has certain values at a given n?. This is definitely part of my misconception

Comment: $\mathcal F_n$ are set of possible events. Knowing the realization of $X_n$ you get to know which event in $\mathcal F_n$ has occured. And this event contains potentially partial information about whether $\omega$ has occured or not.

Comment: right, and within this set lies all the ω that can give us the "future" $X_{m+n}$ but we know nothing more about them. When i said partial realisation i ment of the whole process i,e its values up to $n$