# Sigma-algebras and relationships?

Tags: measure-theory

By reading the post:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19152/why-is-a-topology-made-up-of-open-sets

I find very beautiful to be able to define a topological space as a relationship (the nearness relationship). This definition "explains" naturally why unions can be arbitrary, but intersections only finite.

My question is (the intention to find) an analogy:

Is there the analogous of a "nearness relationship" for sigma algebras?

The reason for my question is that the definition of a sigma algebra is as "non-transparent" as the definition of a topological space. So, if for a topological space there is a relationship (the nearness relationship) that illuminates the meaning and reason for such a non-transparent definition, could there be another relationship, for sigma-algebras, that illuminates the meaning and reason of the usual definition of a sigma-algebra?

Clearly, nearness has a lot to do with topology. What has to do with sigma-algebras? The possibility to measure?

Comment: Others might be able to say something more informative, but to me the sigma-algebra closure properties are simply basic set-constructability/representability properties, and not some abstract way of generalizing a more concrete notion.

Comment: You might be interested in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284728/why-sigma-algebras-represent-information-and-what-information-does-sigmax

Comment: Just as a comment, the formalization of the OP is the Kuratowski closure axioms. So, the initial question can be rephrased as: for sigma algebras, is there an equivalent of what the Kuratowski closure axioms are for topology?

Comment: In https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(mathematics), it is stated that: "In mathematical analysis and in probability theory, the closure of a collection of subsets of X under countably many set operations is called the σ-algebra generated by the collection". Then, putting the closure as a relationship, would allow us to define a sigma-algebra as a structure, right?