# Visualization for Sigma-Algebra

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory

I am reading the Real Analysis book by Folland, and I have found it hard to deal with measure theory.

In set theory, we know that, if $A \subset X$ and $B \subset X$, then $A \cup B \subset X$, and this can be easily shown by Venn diagrams. Now, by Venn diagrams, how can we illustrate, if $A \in X$ and $B \in X$, then $A \cup B \subset X$ or A\B $\subset X$ are not necessarily held?

In general, is there any way like the Venn diagram to visualize a $\sigma$-algebra or similar concepts?

Comment: The sigma algebra contains elements that are subsets of the sampling space; you can do normal Venn diagrams but the base space is the sample space

Comment: I don't think it is helpful to visualize this notion. A $\sigma$-algebra is simply a setting where 'the usual operations of set theory' can take place.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little confusing. Sigma-algebras *do* contain the unions and relative complements that you described.

The point is that if certain sets are in the sigma algebra, then there are certain operations we can apply to sets, like unions, intersections and complements, and we want the sigma algebra to contain the sets that result from some of those operations. Part of the issue is that if we simply allow all subsets to be in the sigma algebra then things go wrong in probability theory for example.

This isn't very visual but some people think of sigma algebras as having to do with information. See here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/230934/visualizing-of-sigma-algebras-as-information

Comment: Connection with information is indeed important. The OP might be interested as well by this reference: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/284744